# Windows 10 running at 100% CPU usage even in safe mode

Tags: windows-10, crash, bsod, cpu-usage

I have been trying to solve the issue with 100% CPU usage on Windows 10. I tried the following:

1. Updated GPU and Intel drivers.
2. Scanned the system for viruses with Malwarebytes, ESET Smart Security and AVG.
3. Disabled tips about Windows in notifications.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Task Manager]

[image: Process hacker]

**Observations:**

1. The most interesting thing is that this issue persists even in Safe Mode!
2. Also, it seems that problem appeared after BSOD with the "CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION" error. WhoCrashed reports the following:

   ```
   This was probably caused by the following module: ntkrnlmp.exe (nt!KeBugCheckEx+0x0)
   ```
3. Process Hacker shows CPU at 1-3%, even though task manager shows it as 100%.

Any ideas? I will be really grateful for any help!

**P.S.** My specs:
i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz;
6.00GB RAM;
NVidia Geforce GTX 660M

Comment: If Task Manager shows 100%, which process is it associated with?

Comment: @Mario: Thank you very much for your response! I do not know which process it is associated with. In fact, as you can see from the screen the CPU usage of all preocesses doesn't even add up to 100%. So, it is a mystery for me as well.